# How do I install Fedora 18 without SELinux?

Tags: linux, fedora

How can I install Fedora 18 without SELinux ever being part of the installation? I don't want to just disable SELinux after it's installed, I want to never install SELinux at all. Is there a way to do this using the CD image and Live System User?

Answer (score 4):

Not without recompiling the kernel and probably a whole bunch of userland utilities. SELinux is, after all, a core part of the Linux kernel, and the system design assumes it will be available, even if not in use.

Since you didn't specify *why* you want to do this ([you should have](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/3608/126632)) it's hard to advise further. Whatever it is, it's probably a bad idea.

To disable SELinux, edit the `/etc/selinux/config` file and set `SELINUX=disabled`. If you're doing a kickstart installation, you can always set this in the `%post` section, so that it's already disabled on first boot.